# PRESTO Left join using multiple operators

Tags: mysql, amazon-presto

- I have 2 tables, one listing all our customers and then a 2nd listing every clients list of creditors/obligations
- Firstly, I need to return all clients in t1 and then be able to determine if the client owns a vehicle or not by looking at t2
- This query seems to do the trick and works as expected

```
    SELECT    t1.first_name,    t1.last_name,    t1.id_number,    CASE
          WHEN
             t2.uid IS NOT NULL 
          THEN
             1 
          ELSE
             0     END    AS vehicle_finance  FROM    db.client t1     LEFT JOIN
          db.obligation t2 
          ON t1.uid = t2.uid
          AND t2.creditor_name LIKE '%Vehicle Finance%'
```

- But recently I discovered additional variants/keywords to include for the creditor name and this is the updated query I came up with

```
    SELECT
       t1.first_name,
       t1.last_name,
       t1.id_number,
       CASE
          WHEN
             t2.uid IS NOT NULL 
          THEN
             1 
          ELSE
             0 
       END
       AS vehicle_finance 
    FROM
       db.client t1 
       LEFT JOIN
          db.obligation t2 
          ON t1.uid = t2.uid
          AND lower(t2.creditor_name) LIKE '%vehicle finance%' 
          OR lower(t2.creditor_name) LIKE '%vehicle and asset finance%' 
          OR lower(t2.creditor_name) LIKE '%vehicle + asset finance%' 
          OR lower(t2.creditor_name) LIKE '%motor finance%'
```

- Can I use the operators(AND & OR) like this in a LEFT JOIN after ON?
- I am not worried about duplicate rows being returned as the client will have several obligations, I have another process that takes care of the duplicates
- Is this query correct and most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Do not use conditions similar to ```... LOWER(column_name) LIKE '%substring%' ...```. Specify explicit case-independent collation instead, like ```... column_name LIKE '%substring%' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ...```.

Comment: Is this purely due to a performance implication? How would I implement the collation in the above query?

Comment: *Is this purely due to a performance implication?* Yes. Collation is applied anycase - explicitly specified or default. *How would I implement the collation in the above query?* ?? I gave you the example. The collation must be specified for each comparing operator separately (4 LIKEs == 4 COLLATE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several inefficiencies, and a few "errors".  That is, I think the query would "run".

- Filtering should go in a `WHERE` clause; `ON` controls how the tables are related.
- Since it looks like you want to filter on `creditor_name`, use `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`.
- `OR` cannot be optimized
- `LIKE '%...` cannot use an index
- `x AND y OR z` is interpreted as `(x AND y) OR z`.  Add parentheses to clarify what you want.
- Since "true" is "1", the `CASE` clause simplifies to just `t2.uid IS NOT NULL AS vehicle_finance`.
- Use a suitable collation *instead of* `lower()` or `upper()`.
- The query looks like it would "run".)

Comment: Thx but I do not want to filter out any records that for example does not =  lower(t2.creditor_name) LIKE '%vehicle finance%'. I simply need to know which client = 0 or 1 for the on condition. Also using JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN would exclude a customer that evaluates to false in the JOIN and I need to return every single customer regardless of this?

Comment: x AND y OR z is interpreted as (x AND y) OR z. Add parentheses to clarify what you want -> but whether I use brackets or not, this is simply for readability purposes right and not actually affecting what the query does?

Comment: @code-is-life - The query given _needs_ the parens to get the desired result.  If is of the other form:  `a=b AND x=1 OR x=2 OR x=3 OR x=4`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use the operators(AND & OR) like this in a LEFT JOIN after ON?

Yes, you can use `AND` and `OR` operators within your `JOIN` clause.

> Is this query correct and most efficient way of achieving this?
> mysql.

The below conditions are going to cause you performance issues with your query.

```
lower(t2.creditor_name) LIKE '%vehicle finance%'
OR lower(t2.creditor_name) LIKE '%vehicle and asset finance%'
```

1. Anytime you wrap a function around a column, such as `lower(t2.creditor_name)`, you are forcing the query engine to convert that column to lowercase for every row in the table, before it can compare it to something.
2. Putting a leading `%` in a `LIKE` condition is the equivalent of looking for `'%oe, John'` in the phonebook instead of `'Doe, Joh%'`. Without knowing the first letter is `D`, someone would have to scan every page of the phonebook to find a record that could be a possible match.

Using these anti-patterns is generally a bad idea, and most often will make it very difficult for the query to utilize an index. You might not notice the impact initially, if your table only has a few hundred rows in it. However, as the data set grows, and you start getting into the 100s of thousands or millions of rows, it will most certainly matter.